# What is this IC? Is there an equivalent?

Tags: power-supply, power, integrated-circuit

[image]

[image]

Is there an equivalent IC for this? This is a 12V power supply. I'm not an electronic expert. I reverse engineered the circuit for fun. I'm not 100% sure about the pin labels though. I guessed them.

Comment: Marking code search brought nothing but your guess about pin labels seems correct. This appears to be an optocoupler-less flyback converter which is quite common in adapters/chargers. The chip has the MOSFET (most likely 600-650V) and the controller inside, and adjusts the output with the help of an aux winding. The internal ref voltage could be 1.25~1.30V, the switching frequency is usually 67kHz. Some controllers are able to decrease it further to reduce no-load consumption down to few milliwatts. Can't say an exact part number but with the help of the info above you can find lots.

Comment: Judging by the markings, it's probably made by [Silergy](https://www.silergy.com/), but there doesn't seem to be a public datasheet available.

Comment: @nanash1 is correct, it is a Silergy part very similar to the SY23416VFAC type parts. It has the same pinout, but  it's probably a custom variant they did for this application.  You may or may not be able to get away with replacing it with a similar Silergy part.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Silergy part very similar to the SY23416VFAC type parts. It has the same pinout, but it's probably a custom variant they did for this application. You may or may not be able to get away with replacing it with a similar Silergy part.